# Extract multiple strings in sqlite and concatenate

Tags: regex, string, sqlite

I have a sqlite database with two fields 'personal' and 'codes'. The 'personal' field has this scheme:

```
Record1: / P00001 Peter James (Indian)/ P00002 Andrew Jackson (Spain)/ ...
Record2: / P00007 Arthur Smith (Greece)/ P00008 Sarha Wang (France)/...
```

I would like to extract all the personal codes in each record, concatenate them using '-' symbol and insert the result into 'Code' field like this:

```
Record1: P00001-P00002-...
Record2: P00007-P00008-...
```

I know how to get the first personal code using substr function but I don't know how to get the rest of the codes.

Could anyone help me to resolve this problem?. Maybe I would need to use regex function but I don't know.

Thank you very much,
Wardiam

Comment: In SQL, this would require a recursive common table expression, which would be insanely complex. Use your script language of choice, or properly normalize the database by putting each piece of data into its own row/column.

Comment: using substr() get all the codes and then split(substr(), '-') This should get your work done. Hope it helps!

Comment: With substr() I could get all codes, it's right, but each record has a different number of personal codes therefore I would not know how many times I need to repeat the text extraction. I need an option that firstly counts the number of codes that I have and then repeats the extraction x times.